# Thread safe StreamWriter C# how to do it? 1

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, streamwriter

What is the best way to build a program that is thread safe in terms that it needs to write double values to a file. If the function that saves the values  via streamwriter is being called by multiple threads? Whats the best way of doing it?

---

Code from comment:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        List<double> Values = new List<double>();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.out");

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) Values.Add(i);

        foreach (double V in Values)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state) { SaveValues(writer, V); }, V);
        }
    }

    static void SaveValues(StreamWriter writer, double Value)
    {
        lock (writer) writer.WriteLine(Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Edit, after decoding the code in your comment

Your problem is **not** with locking or threads but with capturing the loop variable. This is a classic problem, all your threads run with a 'capture' of the single `V` variable, and by the time the threads are executed it will have reached its final value of 999. Except maybe for the first few Workitems.

So, instead of :

```
foreach (double V in Values)
{  
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state) 
        { SaveValues(writer, V); }, V); // use of captured V: almost always 999
}
```

use

```
foreach (double V in Values)
{
    double W = V;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state)
       { SaveValues(writer, W); }, V);
}
```

or, a little more concise,

```
foreach (double V in Values)
{
    double W = V;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => SaveValues(writer, W));
}
```

---

As a variation on @Matti's answer, it is recommended to lock on a separate simple object. This reduces the risk of anything else locking on the same object (the StreamWriter code itself for instance).

```
private StreamWriter writer = ...;         
private Object writerLock = new Object();  // don't expose through a property 
// or any other way

lock (writerLock)
{
    writer.Write(...);
}
```

But the way you have set up the `SaveValues(StreamWriter writer, ...)` method make it a little more complicated. It is better to have an object where `writer` and `writerLock` are both private members.

Comment: I tried both of your methods, but it seems that I have to lock the function that has writer.write(...) in it. If i lock as you have suggested, it only saves a single value/

Comment: Ok one of the methods acutally works till 840, i was suppose to write down 1000 values. But seems to be a reasonable approach, though not 100%

Comment: @Wajih: That's a problem with your Main(). Add `Console.ReadKey(); writer.Close();` as last statements. You're App is closing before the Threads are done.

Comment: Yup, I guess that was a nice tip

Answer (score 7):

[TextWriter.Synchronized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.synchronized.aspx)

> Creates a thread-safe wrapper around the specified TextWriter. ll writes to the returned wrapper will be thread safe.

Answer (score 4):

Lock it while accessing it.

```
lock (myStreamWriter) {
    myStreamWriter.Write(...);
}
```

That gets rid of the problem of multiple threads trying to access it once. Of course, if you need to further ensure that things get written in the right order from multiple threads you'll have to add extra logic.

Comment: OK , I will try it out I guess

Comment: OK So I could not ensure that writing, just two values are written, how do i sync. the flow so that I get all the values written?

class Test
 {
  static void Main()
  {
   List<double> Values = new List<double>();
   StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test");
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    Values.Add(i);
   foreach (double V in Values)
   {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
     (delegate (object state)
    {
     SaveValues(writer, V);
    },V);
   }
  }

  static void SaveValues(StreamWriter writer, double Value)
  {
   lock(writer)
   writer.WriteLine(Value);
  }
 }

Comment: @wajih you should update your question with that.  It is too hard to read as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when doing input or output, I prefer a [producer/consumer queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147.aspx) with only one consumer that does the actual writing of the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can synchronize with a lock on the StreamWriter (or a synchronization object that is used when threads want access to the StreamWriter).  However, when multiple threads are trying to write, only one will be able to continue.

If this is a problem, you can instead implement a queue, and add a writer thread.  The writer thread will dequeue, and write to the StreamWriter.  The other threads will enqueue items instead of writing items directly.

You will have to have some form of synchronization for access to this queue.  You could simply lock it when each thread accesses it.  If you aren't careful, though, could create worse performance problems than you had to begin with.

**Edit**

It looks like Stephen Cleary has a link to an existing .NET class you can use to implement the queue.  I'll leave my answer since it explains why you'd want to do producer/consumer.

Comment: I guess you are right, a queuing system would be best at this point.